# Multiple occurrences of jsp-config element are not allowed in web.xml || weblogic server

Tags: jsp, weblogic

I am getting below error in my weblogic server.

```
<Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101064> <[WebAppModule(*******Application:/)] Error parsing 
    descriptor in Web appplication "********************webApp\WebContent"
    weblogic.descriptor.DescriptorValidateException: The following failures occurred:
    -- Multiple occurrences of jsp-config element are not allowed in web.xml
```

after adding below lines in web.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<web-app>
---------------------------------------------
<jsp-config>
  <jsp-property-group>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    <trim-directive-whitespaces>true</trim-directive-whitespaces>
  </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

Comment: Are their multiple occurrences of the `jsp-config` element in your web.ml?

Comment: I see the same thing with weblogic.  I think it's a bad error message, likely related to the web.xml version 2.3 not supporting the feature?

Answer (score 0):

@Kevin Seifert is correct:

servlet 2.3 web.xml version doesn't have : jsp-config, message-destination, message-destination-ref, and service-ref